# Unable to run "npm run build" -- Getting a MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c#, angular, npm, npm-build

I am trying to publish an application that I have built to my godaddy server. However, when run the npm run build I get the following:

PS C:\Users\trump\Documents\Rider Project\PreChiS-E---Student-DBMS\PreChiS-E---Student-DBMS\PreChiS&EStudentDBMSFrontEnd\node_modules> npm run build

> prechis_e___student_dbms@0.0.0 build
> ng build

'EStudentDBMSFrontEnd\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\trump\Documents\Rider Project\PreChiS-E---Student-DBMS\PreChiS-E---Student-DBMS@angular\cli\bin\ng.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0

From what I believe is happening its not able to find the @angular directory but that directory is listed in the node_modules folder. So its as if node is not see that directory maybe

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall node js. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are calling the build command from the node_modules folder instead of the main angular project folder.

That's why you get the error:

```
'EStudentDBMSFrontEnd\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Change directory to PreChiS&EStudentDBMSFrontEnd and call the build command from there and I think it will work.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. I feel so stupid. Thanks for the help